# Can i use NativeBase with Mobx?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, mobx-react, native-base

My team and i are analyzing the NativeBase framework http://nativebase.io/ for our next project,
our only concern is that they use Redux for their example apps, and we usually pick Mobx for state management. So my question is, is it possible (and safe) to use Mobx with a NativeBase app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With NativeBase, we have used MobX more than Redux for our internal projects and it's been a complete bliss so far!

Go ahead and use NativeBase + MobX for your next project.

Disclaimer: I am a co-author of NativeBase.

Answer (score 3):

I am from NativeBase team. About your question, yes you can use NativeBase with MobX. NativeBase is a UI library and your choice of state-management won't make a difference.

Although all our demo apps use Redux, we have built one of our premium apps with MobX, https://strapmobile.com/native-starter-pro-back-end/.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!  I can't mark more than one as the correct answer, however, you and @KumarSanketSahu answered my question.

Comment: @JorgeJuniorArteagaCarvalho Yes, it happened almost simultaneously. I saw his answer after I posted mine. Nonetheless, I'm glad that you got the answer. :)